# converting unixtime to date in reactjs not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unix-timestamp

I am trying the below code , but my Date is not printing properly. I am getting some different number for year.

```
 const date= = new Date(1607056200000 * 1000);
 let convDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
 console.log("Date is " + convDate + "\n");
```

The output I got is

```
   Date is 8/1/52895
```

But when I tried running the below code, I got correct date and time output

```
let Time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "2-digit",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            second: "2-digit",
          }).format(1607056200000);
          console.log("Time is" + Time + "\n");
```

Output I got

```
Time is 12/04/2020, 10:00:00 AM
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You don't need to multiply by 1000.

Comment: Remove multiply, ex: new Date(1607056200000)

Comment: Oh thank you... I just referred an online site for conversion, and I found that, they multiplied by 1000 so I didn't know why... Thank you... It works now